# Convert 2D float array into 1D array of strings

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a 2D array of floats and I want to convert it into 1D array of strings, where each string is one row of elements from 2D array. I am not getting output in text file as I  expected. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? It will be great help to me, if somebody could provide efficient code with corrections.

```
string[] set = new string[240];

string value = "@"

for (int i = 0; i < 240; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 320; j++)
    {
        value = Convert.ToString(ImageArray[i, j]);
        value += ",";
    }

    set[i] = value + Environment.NewLine;
    value = " ";
}

for(int k=0;k<240;k++)
{
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\mtech\Desktop\sathya.txt", set[k]);
    textBlock1.Text = set[k];
    value = " ";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inside  your inner for loop(j), you are overwriting  the value of `value` variable.

i.e.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 320; j++)
    {
        value = Convert.ToString(ImageArray[i, j]);
        value += ",";
    }
```

instead of above, you should be doing:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 320; j++)
    {
        value += Convert.ToString(ImageArray[i, j]) +",";
    }
```

also, you don't need to perform two nested loops for this task, take a look at [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: yeah !! i realized the mistake after i posted the code, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Here is the shorter way with `LINQ:`

```
var allValues = ImageArray.OfType<float>();
string[] lines = new string[240];
for(int i=0; i<240; i++)
{
   lines[i] = string.Join(",", allValues.Skip(i*320).Take(320));
}

 File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\Users\mtech\Desktop\sathya.txt", lines);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're re-assigning `value` in every iteration in your nested `for` loop. Use the `+=` operator, instead. Another thing you should consider is the use of [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you're going to repeatedly append to a string. `string`s are immutable so you're actually creating a new `string` every time you append to it.

Not sure if this applies to your case (because of the boundaries in your for loops), but you can use LINQ to flatten a multidimensional array. Example:

```
float[,] arr = new float[2,2]
{
    {123.48F, 45.3F},
    {954.23F, 91.3F}
};

var str = string.Join("",
              arr.Cast<float>()
             .Select(x => Convert.ToString(x) + ","));
```